# Is there any helper method to convert boolean string to equivalent tagFilter in Algolia

Tags: ruby, algolia

I'm trying to convert boolean string like `(Book OR Movie) AND SciFi` to equivalent tagFilter query like `[["Book", "Movie"], "SciFi"]`, Is there any helper method to convert boolean string to equivalent tagFilter in Algolia like below.

```
def to_tagfilter(str="(Book OR Movie) AND SciFi")
   # conversion
  [["Book", "Movie"], "SciFi"]
end
```

More read: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/tagFilters/

Comment: I think what you are targeting at, is the so-called (_disjunctive normal form_)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form] of your query.

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with the Algolia support team, ended up writing my own helper method. Assuming it may help for people who may encounter similar requirements.
Caveat: You can write your own validation wrapper on top of this based on the needs.
`

```
ALLOWED_BOOLEAN_OPERATORS = %w(and or not)

def generate_tag_filters(boolean_arr, tag_filter_arr=[])
  return tag_filter_arr if tag_filter_arr.length >= 1 && (boolean_arr & 
    ALLOWED_BOOLEAN_OPERATORS).empty?
  
  boolean_arr.each_with_index do |item , i|
    if item == 'or'
      tag_filter_arr.pop

      if boolean_arr[i+1] == 'not'
        tag_filter_arr << [boolean_arr[i-1], "!#{boolean_arr[i+2]}"]
        boolean_arr.delete_if.with_index { |_, index| index <= i+2 }
      else
        tag_filter_arr << [boolean_arr[i-1], boolean_arr[i+1]]
        boolean_arr.delete_if.with_index { |_, index| index <= i+1 }
      end
      refined_boolean_arr = tag_filter_arr + boolean_arr

      return generate_tag_filters(refined_boolean_arr, tag_filter_arr)
   elsif item == 'and'
     tag_filter_arr.pop
     tag_filter_arr << boolean_arr[i-1]

     if boolean_arr[i+1] == 'not'
        tag_filter_arr << "!#{boolean_arr[i+2]}"
        boolean_arr.delete_if.with_index { |_, index| index <= i+2 }
     else
        tag_filter_arr << boolean_arr[i+1]
        boolean_arr.delete_if.with_index { |_, index| index <= i+1 }
      end
      refined_boolean_arr = tag_filter_arr + boolean_arr

      return generate_tag_filters(refined_boolean_arr, tag_filter_arr)
    elsif item == 'not'
      tag_filter_arr << "!#{boolean_arr[i+1]}"
      boolean_arr.delete_if.with_index { |_, index| index <= i+1 }
      refined_boolean_arr = tag_filter_arr + boolean_arr

      return generate_tag_filters(refined_boolean_arr, tag_filter_arr)
    end
  end
end

##  ['a','and', 'b', 'and', 'not', 'c'] => ["a", "b", "!c"]
puts generate_tag_filters(['a','and', 'b', 'and', 'not', 'c']).inspect
```

`